# HTML5's 'data-' attribute overriding CSS 'content' property

Tags: css, html, css-content

I've looked far and wide and have been unable to find an explanation to this behavior.

**Why does HTML5's `data-` attribute override my CSS `content` property on a common element?**

So for example, I have the following element defined:

```
<th data-module-field="name" class="sortable sorted desc" data-bind="click:sort">Name</th>
```

And my CSS class is as follows:

```
.sortable.sorted.desc:after {
    content: url(../Images/desc.gif);
    margin-left: 3px;
}
```

With the `data-module-field` attribute set, the content image defined in the CSS class doesn't show up. However, if I remove the `data-` portion of this attribute (as follows), the content image displays correctly.

```
<th module-field="name" class="sortable sorted desc" data-bind="click:sort">Name</th>
```

Can anyone explain why this behavior occurs?

Comment: I tried but it seems that it works fine and image show up with data-module-field attribute http://jsfiddle.net/wS82W/1/ may be something else causing issue

Comment: Data attributes should never directly affect CSS generated content. My guess is that there is another CSS rule depending on an `[data-module-field]` attribute selector that's overriding or otherwise preventing your generated content from displaying. See if your browser's Web inspector has any leads.